# How can I set setCancelable(false) for anko dialog in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I can set setCancelable(false) for a dialog in Code B, now I hope to set the same property for an Anko dialog in Code A.

How can I do ? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
private fun deleteBackup(){
    alert(getString(R.string.DialogDeleteContent), getString(R.string.DialogDeleteTitle)) {
        yesButton {    
            //...             
        }
    }.show()
}
```

**Code B**

```
private fun promptBuyWhenExpired() {
    if (IsExpired(applicationContext) ) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.ExpiredTitle))
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.ExpiredWarning))
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.BtnYes)) { dialog, which ->
            finish()
        }
        builder.create().show()
    }
}
```

**Answer:**

I get it, it should be .show().setCancelable(false)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert("message", "title") {
    yesButton {
        //...
    }
    isCancelable = false
}.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code don't work, there is no isCancelable property

Comment: @HelloCW I use anko common library and the property is found at https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/commons/src/dialogs/AlertBuilder.kt#L61     Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Thanks! I get it, it should be .show().setCancelable(false)

Comment: @HelloCW That's good. But my code works. No error in my IDE. The latest version of anko is 0.10.5. I think you may need to update anko version to use isCancelable property.